# Sales OrderController.php moved to my app > local folder and added some custom code

Tags: api, rest-api, order-status, admin-controller

THE ORIGINAL IS STILL IN PLACE.

I'm writing a custom module stored in (local folder) and API (restful api) and i need to know in admin when an ordered is cancelled manually through Sales > Orders. Would it be safe practices to pull the whole sales OrderController.php and right after the cancel function add my code to notify on cancels. ***Obvsiously that's not my user and pw:***

like so:

```
/**
 * Cancel order
 */
public function cancelAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->cancel()
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order has been cancelled.')
            );


**// API Code Start**
$data = array(
'partner_conversion_id' =>  $order->getIncrementId(),
'event_status' => 'decline'
);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.ole.com/v3/events/approve?partner_conversion_id='.$order->getIncrementId().'&event_status=decline');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "6111-1:142dd3d9864d2e858124244");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = ($result);
**// API Code End**


        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been cancelled.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }
}
```

---

Here's my etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Extole_Api>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Extole_Api>
    </modules>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Extole_Api before="Mage_Adminhtml">Extole_Api</Extole_Api>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <models>
        <extole_api>
            <class>Extole_Api_Model</class>
        </extole_api>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you consider "Event - Observer" approach ? Much non-intrusive than this. Far lesser chances of any conflict or bug.

Comment: I writing something like that atm. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, but, what is "atm" ?

Comment: oh.. i'm sorry.. it means "at the moment"